# Any suggestions on what size to make my animation characters?

Tags: animation, transforms, measurement, tools

What are the best sizes that an animation character's XYZ scale measurements average? I am teaching myself how to use the Blender app. By default, the XYZ scales are 1.000 but I think that's too small unless the character is something like a cricket.

Comment: One blender unit is by default 1 meter, that is the "correct" scale to work at, Cycles render engine, light power units, and physics properties all expect that

Answer (score 4):

The sizes are in real-world units, Metric by default.

[image]

These two numbers sound kinda similar but mean very different things.

[image]

When an object has a scale of (1.0, 1.0, 1.0) it basically means "This is how big this object should be by default".

That could be a 50ft building or a 1cm cricket like you describe.

You usually want to keep your scale at 1 because other settings can cause modifiers and other stuff to misinterpret things about your mesh and cause issues.

[image]

Unless you happen to be animating the object or something.

So to answer your question: How big should you character be? As big as they um... are.